# perl/facebook how to get the user id from User object

Tags: facebook, perl, mason

Hi I was looking around the web, but I couldn't find any simple answers on how to get JUST the facebook id from the current user viewing my application. I understand that I need to get the User object from the Graph API and just get the id from that field.  I also understand that I do not need an access token for my case.  I am trying to do this in perl/mason and I was wondering if anyone could help me out with this. I am sorry if this is a duplicate, but I couldnt find that many answers out there with perl / mason

Thank you

Is there something as simple as this in perl /mason?

```
require 'facebook-php-sdk/src/facebook.php';

$facebook = new Facebook(array(
  'appId'  => 'YOUR_APP_ID',
  'secret' => 'YOUR_APP_SECRET',
));

// Get User ID
$user = $facebook->getUser();
```

Answer (score 1):

Check out [this](http://search.cpan.org/~unobe/WWW-Facebook-API-0.4.18/lib/WWW/Facebook/API.pm)

Looks like it will get you what you need.

Though I'm a bit confused what getUser() would return for an application.  You've not specified anything to tell it what user you want, but I'm no facebook expert.

Answer (score 1):

Regarding needing access token, Yes and no

You don't need access token to fetch current use **basic info** just if you use facebook javascript sdk, I guess the example above you posted is facebook php sdk which work in combination with their javascript sdk so I think function getUser actually talk to the javascript side of the SDK

see [facebook javascript sdk](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/javascript/gettingstarted) for example on how to use it

to get user data to your perl app I suggest you use ajax call

after initiating javascript sdk, to get user id

```
//-> /me is for current logged user
FB.api('/me', function(response) {
    alert('Your name is ' + response.name);
    //send response to your perl app
});
```

Other wise authorization process is required and access token is needed.

I'm not sure if there is a perl module that integrates facebook javascript sdk with any templating / mason but I guess this isn't hard to do manually